# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: laravel

Не получается вывести заголовки категорий Laravel.

**Маршрут**:

```
Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog_page')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

**Контроллер**:

```
class SiteController extends Controll
{ 
  protected $menus;

  public function __construct()
  {
    // Коллекция всех менюшек.
    $this->menus = Menu::all();
  }

  public function catalog_page($id)
  {
    // Извлекаем текущую категорию из коллекции.
    $category = $this->menus->find($id);

    // Если категории нет в коллекции, то выдаём 404.
    if(is_null($category)) {
      abort(404, 'Page not found');
    }

    return view('catalog_page', [
      'menus' => $this->menus,
      'category' => $category
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Шаблон `catalog_page`**:

```
<div class="content__right">
  <h1>{{ $category->title }}</h1>
</div>
```

При переходе на страницу выдает ошибку:

> (1/1) NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы опять не указали версию Laravel.

Ошибка **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php** говорит о том, что не найден запрашиваемый маршрут (роут).

**Решение**: убедитесь, что вы действительно переходите/запрашиваете необходимую страницу по адресу, например, `/catalog/{id}`, а не `'/catalog/{alt}'` или `'/catalog/{slug}'`.

---

Помимо этого, довольно часто ошибка возникает, когда при изменении маршрута в кэше хранится старые версии маршрутов. Их очистку и повторное кэширование можно выполнять через командную строку, либо вручную удалить все файлы в папке `bootstrap\cache`, кроме `.gitignore`: так как в этой папке также хранятся кэши.

Небольшой список команд по очистке.

**1** Очистка компилированных шаблонов в папке `\storage\framework\views`:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

**2** Очистка файлов фасада `Cache` в папке `\storage\framework\cache\data`:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**3** Очистка и кэширование файла конфигурации `\bootstrap\cache\config.php`:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**4** Очистка и кэширование файла маршрутов `\bootstrap\cache\routes.php`:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

---

Также данные команды можно вызывать из приложения, например, в одном из контроллере вашей админ. панели:

```
// php

Artisan::call('route:cache');
```

---

**Итог:** если вы вносите изменения в файлы из папки `config`, то необходимо выполнить `config:cache`; внесли изменения в маршруты - `route:cache`.

Comment: Все так же эта ошибка.

Comment: http://public/ - через локальный сервер

Comment: Кажется я нашел в чем проблема, я захожу на главную а там сайдбар категорий, при клике по категории я ожидаю переход на категорию в которой будет титл этой категории, но вместо этого меня перенаправляет на url указанный в сайдбаре. если перейти вот так http://public/catalog/2 то все четко

Comment: Мне щас получается нужно передать в ссылку не url, а переменную $category?

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы лучший!) Только вот как бы мне это все сейчас расчехлить с сайдбаром, что бы сделать красивые url, $menu->id сейчас работает